# Q: incrond - where does SDTOUT and STDERR go?

Tags: incron

Coming from cron I do know that stdout/stderr is mailed to the user executing the script. But incron doesn't seem to have the same functionality. So where do stdout/stderr go to?

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice if it could mail it like cron, but it currently just ignores all output.

As you cannot include redirection(`>` or `>>`) in the command specification the best way seems to be a small script that calls the desired command and redirects the output to a file or mailprogram.

Comment: This is confirmed in the FAQ on http://inotify.aiken.cz/?section=incron&page=faq&lang=en